# What's the "thump" I hear listening to Apollo 11 playback?

Tags: radio-communication, apollo-11

I've been listening to live playback of the Apollo 11 mission at https://apolloinrealtime.org/11/

Besides the expected static and hums, from time-to-time I hear a "thump", sometimes one, sometimes two together.

To me it sounds like someone hitting a piece of PVC pipe with a baseball bat.

Comment: Can you provide a channel and timestamp where this sound can be heard?

Comment: It happens every few minutes, but here's a specific example: 121:04:27

Comment: In which channel? CAPCOM?

Comment: Whatever you're listening to when you don't click on any specific channel. I've gone through every single channel and can't find it, but it is clearly audible on the "combined" channel.  ... I'm going to see if I can figure out how to record a couple seconds of audio from my computer.

Comment: @DarkDust 42:25:46 is one timemark where I hear it, and it's audible on CAPCOM, CAPCOM-R, TRACK, GOSS CONF LOOP, and faintly elsewhere.